# Selective plotting of data and colorbar division

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter

I want to plot only data that is greater than or equal to 6 and less than or equal to 12 on the colorbar. I have written the following. But am unable to include other restrictions:

```
scatter(x(log_gnd>=6), y(log_gnd>=6), 5, log_gnd(log_gnd>=6));
```

I also want to divide the colorbar into only 4 segments.

Comment: I've cleaned up your post. There seems to be two questions here... nevertheless I'm going to answer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot data points greater than or equal to 6 and lower than or equal to 12 ([and function reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html)).

```
indices = log_gnd>=6 & log_gnd<=12;    
scatter(x(indices), y(indices), 5, log_gnd(indices));
```

Concerning the division of colorbar into 4 segments, following code divides colorbar with labels. If you would like for numbers to be there remove `'YTickLabel', {'First', 'Second', 'Third'}` from the code.

```
colorbar('YTick', [7.5 9 10.5], 'YTickLabel', {'First', 'Second', 'Third'});
```

Comment: I am getting following error ??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Comment: I'm sorry; I fixed it. When programming Matlab you should always be keen to test everything in command prompt. Go from `log_gnd>=6` and `log<=12`, then find a way to combine those, etc. That way you're building up the knowledge of intricacies of Matlab.

Comment: Accepting the answer would be a great way to thank - if it helped you! :)